# Python: cannot import name ss

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am using `python 3` in a `jupyter` notebook. When I try to import the following:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import ss
```

I get the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name ss
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the whole implementation of `ss(a, axis)`: `np.sum(a*a, axis)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install statsmodels==0.8.0rc1
```

or with conda

```
conda install -c taugspurger statsmodels=0.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading stats:

```
py -m pip install stats --upgrade
```

Looks like its [deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ss.html) in `scipy 0.17.0`:

Try:

```
 py -m pip install scipy==0.19
```

Comment: I get the following error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-QtVARh/stats/`

Comment: even if i do `pip install stats --upgrade` I get the same error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-JrpjgJ/stats/`

Comment: @emax try `py -m pip install scipy==0.19`

Comment: it works, but when I try to call it on the jupyter notebook I get the same error

Comment: I can install `scipy==0.19` but then if I run `from scipy.stats.stats import ss` on my `jupyter` notebook I get `ImportError: cannot import name ss`

Comment: @emax try `import scipy.stats.ss`

Comment: still the same unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188824/discussion-between-user5173426-and-emax).

Answer (score 0):

Its because 'ss' has been deprecated from Scipy 0.17.

Link: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ss.html